# 3rd gen vios hitting speed bumps even on-angle entry

Tags: toyota, vios

I have a 3rd gen vios, and most of the time I have full passenger (5 total) and sometimes full load on trunk. Most of the time my bottom part hits speed bumps when I am full, even when entering speed bumps on an angle.

I searched and searched the internet but can't find what should I change to prevent this. Most of the topics online are for performance with a single person not for everyday family use.

I'm using all stock Vios 2015 Base J, 14" wheels.

Comment: Even when you go REALLY slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your car is old, then possibly the shocks/springs/dampers are worn/old so the car is both lower than it should be and not responding to the bump as it should.

Otherwise, the Vios is pretty small, and loaded with 5 people it will sit low to the ground, so you may just have to accept that speed bumps are better avoided. I'd suggest you look under the car to see what is actually hitting the ground. It is often part of the exhaust system hanging lower than it should, so this is easy to fix - simply sort out the hook and rubber support.

If it is part of your chassis or the underside of the sump - your only options are to either raise the car - by replacing shocks, springs and possibly other parts of the suspension - or avoid the speed bumps.

Comment: I'm a new driver so I don't know much. will changing to 17" mags/wheel improve my situation?

Comment: Well, it's a 2015 car. I'd go with raising or stiffer shocks. Though would be nice to see what exactly hits.

Comment: 17" will certainly make your ride much harsher, as there is less rubber to soak up bumps. Also, modifying a car from 14" to 17" wheels is a major task for someone new to this. It requires modifications including suspension, possibly wheel arches, track geometry etc.

Comment: my village has a lot of speed bumps and can't be avoided, and in my country there are no standard hump size/height. Its the chassis that scratches on the bumps. I'll go to my local mechanic to look at shocks and suspensions. Thanks

Comment: I guess another option is to not give your friends a lift (joke :-)

Answer (score 0):

try to put [rubber stopper](http://i01.i.aliimg.com/img/pb/348/576/163/1163576348_751.jpg) on the springs, ask your mechanics about this. We have the same car but im using 15", All stock, VIOS e 3rd gen also.